# Is there any semantic difference between "In the school there is a swimming pool" and "In the school is a swimming pool"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In a major reference grammar book, I came across the following two constructions. Unfortunately, it did not mention the difference in meaning between them. I am wondering if there is any semantic difference between them?

> - In the school there is a swimming pool.
> - In the school is a swimming pool.

Comment: None at all; the second uses a slightly more formal style, but 'There's a swimming pool at the school' is the usual conversational variant.

Comment: In this sort of use, *there* is a dummy and has no significance. It can stand there for improved readability or dropped for brevity. The first sounds more common and the second rather formal.

Comment: See https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/it-and-there

Comment: There is one slight difference, an ambiguity that might occur in some contexts.  With "In the school *there* is a swimming pool" the word "there" could be referring to a specific location identified in prior context.  Eg, "Look at the upper-right corner of the map.  In the school there is a swimming pool."  Yeah, it's lousy construction, but completely "legal".

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, but if "in the school there" is a constituent with "there" at the end of that constituent, "there" would have higher stress and would probably be written with a comma after it.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Your interpretation is really convincing. Why don't you answer the question? You know answering a question is much more better than just commenting.